# Get integer which is not in database

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL table :

```
create table example (
    My_Id      INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    My_Integer INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Suppose this table to be populated like that :

```
SELECT * FROM `example`

My_Id   My_Integer
1       10
2       1
3       3
4       152
5       16
6       481
7       128
```

My goal is to retrieve, from an user input, which integer is not in my table 'example'.

For example, if the user enter 1, 3, 10, the result should be empty.
If the user enter 1, 2, 3, 10, the result should be "2".

I can't find a way to do that, other than to do one MySQL request per integer in order to know if the number is in the table 'example'.
Do someone know a way ?

Comment: As i say, I prefere to have the result directly with a MySQL request. The problem is that i'm not familiare with MySQL, so I just want to know if there is a way, because in my program, there will be much more than 7 integer in the table, and the 'user' will be a script  which will input more than 3 integer.

Comment: Using right outer join and select those null record in left table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select numberToMatch
from example as a 
right outer join (
  select 1 as numberToMatch union all 
  select 2 union all 
  select 3 union all 
  select 10
) as b 
on b.numberToMatch = a.My_Integer
where a.My_Integer is null
```

Using right outer join and select those null record in the left table.

Comment: Thanks, I see that answer like an another use of the keyword "union". I will test it first. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could genereate tally table and use `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.n
FROM (
  SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + 1 n
  FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
      UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
      UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
    ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
      UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
      UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
      UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
      UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
    ) t
LEFT JOIN example e
 ON t.n = e.My_Integer
WHERE t.n IN (1,2,3,10)     -- here goes numbers
  AND e.My_Integer IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/KTVL57708)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══╗
║ n ║
╠═══╣
║ 2 ║
╚═══╝
```

It will work in range `1-999`. You could expand it if needed.

---

Another way is to use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT s.col
FROM (SELECT 1 AS col
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 10) AS s
LEFT JOIN example e
  ON s.col = e.My_Integer
WHERE e.My_Integer IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/LNW24579)**</kbd>

Comment: Nice ! I didn't know the "union" trick, i will read about it. Thanks !